# How to to hide text and show on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one dark division box I want to develop such thing when you click and hold mouse over div one round shape div will transparent and it will show hidden sentence under that dark div.

Answer (score 0):

give that div box a class e.g darkBox then in css 
u can also give "active" property for clicking
border-radius can make it round, if u give 50% it will make it circle, if u want corner edges round or curved u can give values less than this

```
.darkBox:hover{
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I hope this helps ,if not can you please tell me what u exactly require

Answer (score 0):

Key point:

- A round shape can easily be made by using [`border-radius: 50%`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/).
- The pseudo-class [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) is what activates the alternate state.
- The pseudo-class [`:before`](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/) (and `:after`) can insert into an element some text.
- The extra fading effects were done with [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

```css
.orb {
  font-size: 3em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
}
.orb:before {
  content: '\2620';
  transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in, color 4s linear;
  opacity: 0;
  color: transparent;
}
.orb:hover:before {
  content: '\2620';
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}
.cap:after {
  content: '';
  transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in, color 4s linear;
  opacity: 0;
  color: transparent;
}
.orb:hover .cap:after {
  content: 'The skull and crossbones is actually a font character';
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
  font: 400 16px/.3 'Palatino Linotype';
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<figure class="orb">
  <figcaption class="cap"></figcaption>
</figure>
```